# Is there a way to combine multiple takes in a TF2 Replay?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I had an awesome double kill when I was playing as Pyro tonight;

I wanted to set it up so that first you had the first-person-view, (of me) and then you had a 3rd person view of the area the fight was taking place in.

I got two separate "takes", one from each perspective, but I can't seem to figure out how to append the one to the other. Is this possible to do within TF2 itself?

Otherwise, it looks like I might have to create a movie from both takes and then use some video editing software to stitch them together outside of the game itself (which would be hard for me, as I lack video editing software).

Is there a way to combine multiple takes in a TF2 Replay?

Comment: heh....that was pretty darn-tootin' good...

Comment: It was complete serendipity that "Rock the Casbah" was playing on the server at that moment. (The map of course, is ctf_Casbah).

Comment: Casbah?  You must have been on our server :)

Comment: @Dave - it was! Though you and most of the others had already left by that point. It was down to a 3 v. 3.

Comment: Last month, I had a triple kill against a Kritzed Demo, his Medic, and a Pyro who was blocking my ÜberCharge, with one airblast. Unfortunately, replays weren't available yet then, but I have a screenshot...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently the TF2 editor is not able to do this, maybe in the future but for now you'll need an external editor.

If you are using windows, you should have the *Windows Movie Maker* installed already, though it is not a very good editor.

If you just want to stitch together 2 videos, you can do that with the *YouTube Video Editor*: http://www.youtube.com/editor

Comment: Ooh, that looks promising.

Comment: I can tell you with absolute certainty that the TF2 editor will not be able to do this kind of thing ever, since it's based on demos which only work one way, chronologically.